# Why can't I get more than 60 FPS in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, performance

How can I overcome low fps on NVIDIA Geforce 940 MX? I get only 60 fps. This is frustating as this graphics card should be good enough for this light weight game.

#### Graphics

- Driver version : 391.01
- Direct 3D API Version: 12
- Direct 3D Feature Level: 11_0
- CUDA Cores: 384
- Graphics Clock: 1122 Mhz
- Memory data rate: 1800 Mhz
- Memory Interface: 64-bit
- Memory Bandwith: 14.40 GB/s
- Total available Graphics memory: 8134 MB
- Dedicated Video memory: 4096 MB DDR3
- System Video Memory: 0 MB
- Shared System Memory: 4038 MB
- Video BIOS Version: 82.08.59.00.75
- IRQ: Not used
- Bus: PCI Express x4 Gen3

#### PC

- OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit
- DirectX Run time version: 12.0
- Processor: Intel i7 7500U @2.70 Ghz
- Memory: 8192 MB RAM

This question isn't certainly a duplicate of "Can my PC run this game?" It obviously can run the game. My question is related to how can I improve the fps? No one else has asked a question with my exact configuration. I have already tried many tweaks and setting video quality to low but still failed to increase
FPS. So I have included my PC's specifications to hope for a solution specific to my problem.
*So why has it been marked duplicate?*

Steps I had tried:
Setting all video settings to low and everything that radu has recommended in his answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it is now clear that your computer indeed does support the game with acceptable FPS it is definitely a problem with your VSync settings.

There are now two things left to do:

Since Windows 10 may block/override your VSync settings you should disable that option:

1. Right-click the CSGO.exe
2. Go to Compatibility
3. Check the box for *Disable fullscreen optimizations*

[image]

Also make sure you have VSync off in your NVidia Control Panel. It is set to *adaptive* by default. Change it to *off* in your 3D Settings if you haven't done that yet. And you probably have done that already, but also make sure VSync is set to off in your in-game settings.

Now your FPS should be fine and you can change it to whatever you like using `fps_max <value>` in-game or in your config.

Comment: There is also a vsync setting within the games graphics settings which would need to be off. You might want to mention that.

Comment: @kenjara according to the other comments (including deleted ones) the in-game setting is already off, but I can still add it.

Answer (score 4):

As others stated you should tweak the in game settings, I have a gtx 980ti and still keep everything on the lowest setting just because the extra detail is not necessary. The only thing that should not be to the lowest setting is shadow quality. At it's lowest settings you do not see them and that is a major issue. Just go one level above lowest.

Also you may have noticed a wierd resolution when you see streamers online. That's because they play on a resolution lower than 1080 and in an aspect ratio that is not 16/9.

It may sound bad at first but this is the way that most pros play and it does have its advantage. What you would want to do is set your resolution to 1024xXXX or even 800x600 and set your aspect ratio to 4:3 (think of the old CRT monitors). once you have these settings you will have black bars on the left and right hand side of your screen (due to the difference in aspect ratio). Some people like to play with black bars some don't. Try out and see what you like.

In order to get rid of the black bars you will have to play in what is considered stretch mode. All you have to do is set the launch option to `-fullscreen`. Here is a guide that goes more into detail: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=546255142

Here is s1mple's settings, you can see he plays on a Stretched scaling:
http://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/S1mple

Here is pashaBiceps' settings, he is a player who uses black bars:
http://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/Pasha

With your set up you will be able to get over 100 fps, the rest is just tweaking it to whatever you feel comfortable with. This is not a game that is meant to look good, and you really wont care about the level detail when your team beats someone 16-0 in comp.

Comment: You can also stretch the screen in your GPU control panel; by choosing an option to run all programs (or just CS:GO) "fullscreen".  I assume it essentially acts identically to the launch option; just applied from a different place.

Answer (score 3):

In Video settings, make sure that your FPS isn't capped, which prevents it from going higher than a certain number.

Comment: 20 FPS is unplayable. Do one comp match and you will see. I find even 60FPS to be too low.

Comment: My FPS isn't capped. Thanks for your response. A higher FPS will make  playing the game more fluid when I look around.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been covered in the deleted comments but I think it is worth mentioning for anyone else viewing this question now.

In addition to the answers about the output and performance of your PC, in order to see the extra frames you will need a monitor capable of displaying more than 60fps.

Most standard PC monitors will have a refresh rate of 60hz, this is the maximum number of frames per second the monitor is capable of displaying. Monitors designed for gaming, especially competitive gaming, usually have refresh rates of 120-144hz and sync the GPU output to the monitor refresh rate. Some of the newer ones even go up to 240hz.

It doesn't matter if your PC is capable and set up to run a game at 100fps, if the monitor can only display at 60hz you will still play at 60fps.

Of course you can render the game at 100fps with a 60hz monitor which has benefits like lower input latency and drawbacks like screen tearing but to get the best results you need a capable monitor.

Comment: The question being: is CS:GO rendering framerate to your screen refresh rate? And I don't think so. This won't change what you see on the screen (mostly) but will change mouse acceleration, the settings passed to the netcode, etc. In short, it's not that simple.

Comment: To play a game at 100fps you need a monitor that can display at 100hz, it is that simple. I posted this answer to give additional information to anyone coming to this question cold so that they have a full picture of what is is required to game at over 60fps. There are already two other answers dealing with performance and v-sync. The monitor is really the last part of equation for high frame rate gaming.

Comment: "To play a game at 100fps you need a monitor that can display at 100hz." No, just no. You can have a rendering framerate different from the refresh rate of your monitor. It's not that simple, and I did not get into details about vsync on/off on that topic or more settings that could affect this, but CS:GO has its rendering independent to the refresh rate. Just run the game with the debug monitor, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I disagree. If you are rendering at 100fps on a monitor that only has a refresh rate of 60hz you are not seeing 100fps you are seeing 60fps max and you could be seeing less if they are not synced. There might be other reasons for wanting to render at higher rates that your monitor can display and that might even the case in this question but if you want play at true 100fps you need a monitor capable of displaying 100fps. I stand by that as useful and relevant information regarding this question.

Comment: Please, do not make me say something I did not. I did not say you could "see more images" with a refresh rate lower than your framerate. You are not listening. I just said that, in the way you describe the situation (I am quoting one your wrong sentences: "To play a game at 100fps you need a monitor that can display at 100hz.") you were wrong. End of story. Therefore, these information you are broadcasting are, at best, misleading.

Comment: We are debating the semantics about what 'playing at 100fps' means. I define playing at 100fps as seeing 100fps and to see 100fps you need a capable monitor. Playing a game running at 100fps on a 60hz monitor has benefits and drawbacks, it is not the best solution and I don't think it is reasonable to describe it as playing at 100fps because you are not seeing 100fps. By these definitions my statement "To play a game at 100fps you need a monitor that can display at 100hz." is correct because to play a game you need to see it.

Comment: Comments are not really for extended discussion, I have edited my answer improve it based on your comments further to that, lets just agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the settings to run the game in fullscreen windowed mode worked for me. I got from 60 to 400 FPS

Comment: Can you explain how to change the settings to windowed mode?